# matplotlib.pyplot errorbar ValueError depends on array length?

Tags: arrays, matplotlib

Good afternoon.

I've been struggling with this for a while now, and although I can find similiar problems online, nothing I found could really help me resolve it.

Starting with a standard data file (.csv or .txt, I tried both) containing three columns (x, y and the error of y), I want to read in the data and generate a line plot including error bars.

I can plot the x and y values without a problem, but if I want to add errorbars using the matplotlib.pyplot errorbar utility, I get the following error message:

`ValueError: yerr must be a scalar, the same dimensions as y, or 2xN.`

The code below works if I use some arbitrary arrays (numpy  or plain python), but not for data read from the file. I've tried converting the tuples which I obtain from my input code to numpy arrays using asarray, but to no avail.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

row = []
with open("data.csv") as data:
    for line in data:
        row.append(line.split(','))

column = zip(*row)

x = column[0] 
y = column[1]
yer = column[2]

plt.figure() 
plt.errorbar(x,y,yerr = yer)

fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(18.5, 10.5)
fig.savefig('example.png', dpi=300)
```

It must be that I am overlooking something. I would be very grateful for any thoughts on the matter.

Comment: you know you can use `np.genfromtxt` or `np.loadtxt` to read your file in, right? Easier than having to split it yourself.

Comment: Thank you. I was actually unaware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`yerr` should be the added/subtracted error from the `y` value. In your case the added equals the subtracted equals half of the third column.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.loadtxt('data.csv', delimiter=',')

plt.figure()
yerr_ = np.tile(data[:, 2]/2, (2, 1))
plt.errorbar(data[:, 0], data[:, 1], yerr=yerr_)
plt.xlim([-1, 3])
plt.show()
```

data.csv

```
0,2,0.3
1,4,0.4
2,3,0.15
```

Comment: Thank you so much, both for solving the actual problem and the shortcut to reading in data. I've done an introductory course to scientific python, but have never encountered this.

Comment: The use of slices to extract the columns is very clever, took me a while to fully appreciate.